# Problems with BeautifulSoup and processing text results

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup, insert

I scraped a website using BeautifulSoup and after printing the results I get 2 lines of text then 2 line breaks and then another 2 lines of text. Perfect.

However, when I insert this lump of text-lines-text into the body of an email, only the last 2 lines of text appear. Why did the first 2 lines of text and 2 lines breaks disappear?

Here is my code:
Note.I have removed the email addresses for the sender and recipient and password.

Many thanks!

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import smtplib

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://webshop.meyerskantiner.dk/shop/2240/take-away/g/23332?date=22-02-2019').read()

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

for hit in soup.find_all("div", class_="name"):
    msg1 = hit.get_text()

msg2 = 'Subject: Canteen Intelligence\nHello,\n\nHere is the menu for the week.\n' + '\n\n\n\n' + msg1
conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
conn.ehlo()
conn.starttls()
conn.login('SendersEmail', "password")
conn.sendmail('SendersEmail', ['RecipientsEmail'],msg = msg2.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
conn.quit()

print(msg2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for hit in soup.find_all("div", class_="name"):
    msg1 = hit.get_text()
```

Each time this loop executes, it discards the previous contents of `msg1`.  When the loop is done, `msg1` will contain only the final hit.

Try this instead:

```
msg1 = ""
for hit in soup.find_all("div", class_="name"):
    msg1 = msg1 + hit.get_text()
```

Comment: I had no idea there was a loop occurring in this code. Thanks for pointing this out, John. I will look into appending (joining together) the results of this loop and then adding that to the email body text. Back in touch soon.

Comment: I have spent a few hours on this but I still can't get all hits from find_all into the email body text. I've tried using append. I've searched online. But so far no luck. Are you able to help me out further?

Comment: That did the trick! Many thanks John. (fyi, I have upvoted your answer but I don't have more than 15 reputation points so it's recorded but won't appear).